Suscripciones mercado pago - Error al generarse la factura (cc_rejected_high_risk)
Tengo el siguiente problema a ver si alguien sabe como solucionar:
Lo que estoy haciendo es una integración programática utilizando el API de Mercado pago, basándome en el sistema de suscripciones automáticas y haciendo uso del CardBrick para desarrollos informáticos. No los hago manualmente o compartiendo QR ni link.

/* Aca lo que se hace es generar el token de 
** la tarjeta y mandarlo al BE
*/

function CardPaymentBrickReact({ suscription, planId, userLoged, onExecution }) {

  const handleApprobeReject = async (status, paymentId) => {
    onExecution(status, paymentId);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    initMercadoPago(MP_PUB_KEY);
  }, []);

  const initialization = {
    amount: suscription.amount,
  };

  const onSubmit = async (formData) => {
    try {
      const userString = JSON.stringify(userLoged);
      const approbe = await saveSuscriptionPreaproval(suscription.amount, planId, userString, formData);
      if (approbe.status !== 200) {
        throw new Error('Error al aprobar la suscripción');
      }
      handleApprobeReject(true, approbe.data.id);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error en la transacción', error);
      handleApprobeReject(false, null);
      return false;
    }
  };

  const onError = (error) => {
    handleApprobeReject(false, null);
      return false;
  };

  // Función que se llama cuando el Brick está listo
  const onReady = () => {
    console.log('Brick listo');
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <CardPayment
        initialization={initialization}
        onSubmit={onSubmit}
        onReady={onReady}
        onError={onError}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default CardPaymentBrickReact;

El flujo es el siguiente: Renderizo el carbrick, obtengo el token una vez que el usuario pone sus datos y hace submit. (no hago ninguna creacion de pago, solo obtengo el token ya que el pago en suscripciones deberia ser automatico). Luego de conseguir el token se envía el preapprove de la suscripción al api de MP. Previamente ya tengo en mi DB el preapprobe plan al que se asociara la suscripcion.
@Injectable()
export class SuscriptionServiceImpl extends SuscriptionService {


/* 
** El BE recibe el token, lo envia al API de MP
** haciendo el post https://api.mercadopago.com/preapproval
** se recibe la respuesta y persisto al usuario suscripto
** luego de ello espero el webhook para consultar la factura
*/

    async preapprobe(request: MeliSuscriptionPreapprobalRequest): Promise<Boolean> {
        console.log("Preaprobando suscripcion ---->", request.data);
        try {
            const responseObject: MeliSuscriptionResponse = await this.preapproveSuscription(request);
            console.log("Respuesta de la suscripcion ---->", responseObject);
            if(parseInt(responseObject.status) === 500){
                throw new PaymentException(ErrorCode.ERROR_CREATING_SUSCRIPTION, ErrorMessage.ERROR_CREATING_SUSCRIPTION, 500);
            }
            await this.saveUserSuscribed(responseObject, request.planId);
            if (PaymentConstants.STATUS_SUSCRIPCION_HABILITADOS.includes(responseObject.status)) {
                return true;
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error creando la suscripcion: ", error);
            throw error;
        }
    }

    private async preapproveSuscription(request: MeliSuscriptionPreapprobalRequest): Promise<MeliSuscriptionResponse> {
        const UUID = await this.createUniqueUUID()
        const startDate = new Date().toISOString();
        const futureYear = new Date().getFullYear() + 2;
        const endDate = new Date(startDate);
        endDate.setFullYear(futureYear);
        const formattedEndDate = endDate.toISOString();
        try {
            const response = await fetch('https://api.mercadopago.com/preapproval', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    "Authorization": `Bearer ${ACCESS_TOKEN}`,
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                },
                body: this.getSuscriptionPreapprobalBody(request, UUID, startDate, formattedEndDate)
            });
            const responseObject: MeliSuscriptionResponse = await response.json();
            responseObject.usr_email = request.data.email;
            return responseObject;
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error creando el modelo de usuario suscrito: ", error);
            throw error;
        }
    }


    private async createUniqueUUID(): Promise<string> {
        let uuid: string;
        do {
            uuid = uuidv4();
        } while (await SuscribedUser.findOne({ where: { id_suscription: uuid } }));

        return uuid;
    }


    private getSuscriptionPreapprobalBody(request: MeliSuscriptionPreapprobalRequest
        , UUID: string, startDate: string, formattedEndDate: string) {
        return JSON.stringify({
            "preapproval_plan_id": request.planId,
            "reason": PaymentConstants.REASON,
            "external_reference": UUID,
            "payer_email": request.data.email,
            "card_token_id": request.data.token,
            "auto_recurring": {
                "frequency": 1,
                "frequency_type": PaymentConstants.FRECUENCY_M,
                "start_date": startDate,
                "end_date": formattedEndDate,
                "transaction_amount": request.amount,
                "currency_id": PaymentConstants.CURRENCY_ARS
            },
            "back_url": "https://www.your-site.com/home",
            "status": "authorized",
        })
    }
}

Finalmente lo que se hace es esperar la confirmación por un webhook. Con el webhook se corrobora la información de la factura. Y el problema es que en la factura y en webhook de pago siempre me sale rechazado (cc_rejected_high_risk). Cabe destacar que el webhook me llega aprox 1:30 o 2hs despues
Que me estoy perdiendo? Que mas me falta? SI TE INTERESA Y SABES COMO PODES AYUDARME, te dejo un repo publico que arme para que veas a razgos generales mi codigo: https://github.com/augustoocch/mp-suscripcion/tree/main
Aca encontre una implementacion de alguien que hace un payment.save(), pero eso no esta en la documentacion. Los pagos no deberian ser automaticos? Paso referencia: https://github.com/adrianiux38/mercadoPago-subscription/blob/main/static/js/index.js
Yendo a la docu de mercado pago, la parte de procesar el pago se la saque. Porque justamente lo que quiero es unicamente el token para generar la suscripcion. Osea, esta pieza de codigo que ejecuta el pago, la uso en los pagos unicos, pero para suscripciones lo removi:
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                  fetch("/process_payment", {
                    method: "POST",
                    headers: {
                      "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify(cardFormData)
                  })
https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/live-demo/card-payment-brick

Datos de color: Los pagos individuales comunes salen perfecto. La diferencia es que ejecuto manualmente el pago. Ademas de ello, en ambos casos estoy usando una tunelizacion de MP a mi backend para que lleguen los webhooks (que no creo que interfiera, ya que con los pagos comunes pasan perfecto y el pago se aprueba)
Espero que el webhook de pago llegue como aprobado y que la factura este aprobada tambien. Lo que pasa es que llega como desaprobado
